# How to make a sorting button on access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm developing an Access DB and I'd like do implement 2 buttons that, when clicked down, sort my subform "SUBForm1" according to parameters: asceding alphabetic order by NAME and one another ascending by Month.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "acCmdSortAscending" method.

For example;

```
Private Sub btnSortByName_Click()

Forms!frmYourForm![SUBForm1].SetFocus
[fldName].Form![fldName].SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending
```

Comment: Hi, Thank´s for the help. Well, it had worked fine on the first situatin. Sortting by name, but, trying to do the same thing on the filed MONTH, i´v got the following error: 

Error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"

I believe tha´s because the field Month is provenient from a query - month:format([date_contact];"mm") and maybe it has the data type definided as Date. What do you think?

Thank´s a lot!